# Pass $_POST data using include statement

Tags: php

This is a statement used in a function named 'handlejoin' in my api which lets users in my app join a chat.

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO active_users (user_Id, device_token, nickname, secret_code, ip_address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->execute(array($userId, $token, $name, $code, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
```

I want to pass the `$token` value to a new file. I want to do this using an include statement like this.

```
<?php
include: 'api.php'
echo "$token";
?>
```

The only thing is that the handleJoin statement is in a file (api.php) that has a lot of code and I'm not yet sure how to comprehend the current variable scope of the `$token` variable enough to successfully pass its value to a new file. There seem to be a lot of nuances of the include statement pertaining to variable definitions etc. Can someone help me parse the api/php file in its entirety to learn how to successfully pass the `$token` variable's contents to another file?

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Here is the whole file: https://github.com/tonycrencren/api-file/blob/master/api.php

The handleJoin statement is on line 192

**Edit: more info**

My app uses push notifications. The $token variable I want to pass stores the device token. I can echo out the device token in the NSLog like this.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{ 
NSString* newToken = [deviceToken description];
newToken = [newToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
newToken = [newToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

NSLog(@"My token is: %@", newToken);

}
```

Output in NSLog

[image]

The device token also gets posted to the database when the join function is called. Note that its the same device token.

[image]

testfile.php

```
<?php

//tells you whats going on in the browser at at what line if there needs to be an improvement to the structure of the function

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);


function token()
 {
include 'file://localhost/Users/user/Desktop/PushChatServer/api/api.php';

echo "A $token";

return $token;

}

token();  
echo "$token"; 


?>
```

Question: how can I make a new file and successfully echo the `$token` variable from api.php out in the new file using an include statement? I want to be able to see the device token string when I open the new file in my web browser. Right now its a blank web page. I get the hunch that the new file isn't getting the variable at all.

I also get the hunch that even if it is getting the `$token` value, I'd have to run the app simultaneously so that method is called and also keep refreshing the new web page in order to see the token value. Correct?

Comment: The function should return the token. After the include you should call the function which will return the token.

Comment: Ok Shadow, I'll give it a shot. I've also updated the question with some more examples of how the device token is used.

Comment: I updated the question with the code you suggested but still no output. Can you verify that I uploaded the correct code? I know I used echo twice, but I did that just in case.

Comment: 2 ways to do it. 
1st - include api.php and do anything to get $token like function return, set is as as class property then get it, etc. 2nd without file include, if you are using $_POST and not used header function then it's still in $_POST so can get it from there or tricky way set it to session ;)

Comment: if $_POST is blank, then u can try $_SESSION but remember u have to manage that if you have multiple query then token will update or use array of $_SESSION['myStoredToken'][] to store tokens. Use echo token(); in example. You can also declare $token as global variable and can get without function  (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: I really like the idea of setting a global variable.

Comment: How would I set it as a global variable in the api.php file? Would I have to do it in everywhere the `$token` variable is used? Or just one line? Update in progress.

Answer (score 1):

Since the included file is executed as if it was part of the caller file, just create a global variable within the api.php file and make sute it is set, e.g. call the `token()` function within the api.php.

api.php

```
//declare global $token variable
$token='';

//function that generates the token
function generate_token() {
...
}

//use one of the following methods
//code to execute the generate_token() function if generate_token() returns the token
$token=generate_token();

//code to execute the generate_token() function if generate_token() sets the global $token within the function's body
//put a declaration within generate_token() in order to set $token global variable from the function: global $token;
generate_token();
```

You can use your testfile.php with the above code.

However, I would not do it this way. I would create the generate_token() function within the api.php that returns the token. In the test php you include the api.php and call the function:

api2.php:

```
//function that generates the token
function generate_token() {
...
return ...; //returns the token
}
//end api2.php
```

test.php:

```
include api2.php;
echo generate_token();
```

Comment: I'm having trouble passing any variables declared in the `api.php` file to the test file. Could it be the `private pdo` connection thats being used? I've asked a new question that will hopefully help me figure out where exactly to declare a global variable in `api.php` in order to pass it to a new file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191810/where-to-put-global-variable-declarations-in-a-robust-file

Comment: Any ideas? $token can wait, right now I just want to pass ANY variable to the test file. No matter where I declare them, nothing shows up when I echo it from test.php

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what and how you have tried. The techniques I described above work. If you want me to update the answer, then provide **meaningful** feedback, not just that "it does not work"!

Comment: Originally I wasn't able to yet pass any global variables from `api.php` to a `Test.php` file. Now I can , but only after deleting lines 7 - 130 in the github source file linked in the question. Just by looking at that code from 7 - 130 have you any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Perhaps it catches an error, therefore $api variable is not set to an instance of the api class?