# Where to put global variable declarations in a robust file?

Tags: php, pdo

I have a php file named `api.php`. I want to use its data in another file in an include statement. I need to make the data first `global` so it can be used as a `variable`. I create a file named `Test.php` like this:

```
//Test.php
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

//Changed include to require
require 'include file://localhost/Users/user/Desktop/PushChatServer/api/api.php';

echo "$Global_Variable";

?>
```

Then I set up the `$Global_Variable` variable in the `api.php` file like this:

```
global $Global_Variable;
$Global_Variable = 'This is a sentence.';
```

The only thing is, the api.php file has a lot of code in it and no matter where I seem to place the global variable, nothing gets echoed out at all in test.php. Any ideas as to why? It works when I put the same global variable in a new empty php file. Here is the full `api.php` file in its entirety. I know its a lot of code at 429 lines. It uses `private` pdo connections and has a class declarations. Could that be why? Is there a way to make those global to?

```
<?php

//Added Require Statement
require 'Test.php';


//This doesn't echo out anything when called from Test.php
global $Global_Variable;
 $Global_Variable = 'This is a sentence';

// This is the server API for the PushChat iPhone app. To use the API, the app
// sends an HTTP POST request to our URL. The POST data contains a field "cmd"
// that indicates what API command should be executed.

try 
{
// Are we running in development or production mode? You can easily switch
// between these two in the Apache VirtualHost configuration.
if (!defined('APPLICATION_ENV'))
    define('APPLICATION_ENV', getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production');

// In development mode, we show all errors because we obviously want to 
// know about them. We don't do this in production mode because that might
// expose critical details of our app or our database. Critical PHP errors
// will still be logged in the PHP and Apache error logs, so it's always
// a good idea to keep an eye on them.
if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

}
else
{
    error_reporting(0);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
}

// Load the config file. I prefer to keep all configuration settings in a
// separate file so you don't have to mess around in the main code if you
// just want to change some settings.
require_once 'api_config.php';
$config = $config[APPLICATION_ENV];

// In development mode, we fake a delay that makes testing more realistic.
// You're probably running this on a fast local server but in production
// mode people will be using it on a mobile device over a slow connection.
if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
    sleep(0);
//here
// To keep the code clean, I put the API into its own class. Create an
// instance of that class and let it handle the request.

$api = new API($config);
$api->handleCommand();

echo "OK" . PHP_EOL;

}
catch (Exception $e)
{
// The code throws an exception when something goes horribly wrong; e.g.
// no connection to the database could be made. In development mode, we
// show these exception messages. In production mode, we simply return a
// "500 Server Error" message.

if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
    var_dump($e);
else
    exitWithHttpError(500);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function exitWithHttpError($error_code, $message = '')
{
switch ($error_code)
{
    case 400: header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request"); break;
    case 403: header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"); break;
    case 404: header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); break;
    case 500: header("HTTP/1.0 500 Server Error"); break;
}
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

if ($message != '')
    header('X-Error-Description: ' . $message);
exit;
}

function isValidUtf8String($string, $maxLength, $allowNewlines = false)
{

if (empty($string) || strlen($string) > $maxLength)
    return false;

if (mb_check_encoding($string, 'UTF-8') === false)
    return false;

// Don't allow control characters, except possibly newlines 
for ($t = 0; $t < strlen($string); $t++)
{
    $ord = ord($string{$t});

    if ($allowNewlines && ($ord == 10 || $ord == 13))
        continue;

    if ($ord < 32)
        return false;
}

return true;
}


function truncateUtf8($string, $maxLength)
{
$origString = $string;
$origLength = $maxLength;

while (strlen($string) > $origLength)
{
    $string = mb_substr($origString, 0, $maxLength, 'utf-8');
    $maxLength--;
}

return $string;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


 class API
{
// Because the payload only allows for 256 bytes and there is some overhead
// we limit the message text to 190 characters.
const MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 190;

private $pdo;

function __construct($config)
{
    // Create a connection to the database.
    $this->pdo = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'], 
        $config['db']['username'], 
        $config['db']['password'],
        array());

    // If there is an error executing database queries, we want PDO to
    // throw an exception. Our exception handler will then exit the script
    // with a "500 Server Error" message.
    $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // We want the database to handle all strings as UTF-8.
    $this->pdo->query('SET NAMES utf8');
}

function handleCommand()
{

    // Figure out which command the client sent and let the corresponding
    // method handle it. If the command is unknown, then exit with an error
    // message.
    if (isset($_POST['cmd']))
    {
        switch (trim($_POST['cmd']))
        {
            case 'join': $this->handleJoin(); return;
            case 'leave': $this->handleLeave(); return;
            case 'update': $this->handleUpdate(); return;
            case 'message': $this->handleMessage(); return;
        }
    }

    exitWithHttpError(400, 'Unknown command');
}

// The "join" API command registers a user to receive notifications that
// are sent in a specific "chat room". Each chat room is identified by a
// secret code. All the users who register with the same secret code can
// see each other's messages.
//
// This command takes the following POST parameters:
//
// - user_Id:  A unique identifier. Must be a string of 40 hexadecimal characters.
// - token: The device's device token. Must be a string of 64 hexadecimal
//          characters, or "0" if no token is available yet.
// - name:  The nickname of the user. Must be a UTF-8 string of maximum 255
//          bytes. Only the first 20 bytes are actually shown in the push 
//          notifications.
// - code:  The secret code that identifies the chat room. Must be a UTF-8
//          string of maximum 255 bytes.
//


function handleJoin()
{
    //function getUserId;
    $userId = $this->getUserId();
    $token = $this->getDeviceToken(true);
    $name = $this->getString('name', 255);
    $code = $this->getString('code', 255);

    // When the client sends a "join" command, we add a new record to the
    // active_users table. We identify the client by the user_id that it
    // provides. When the client sends a "leave" command, we delete its
    // record from the active_users table.

    // It is theoretically possible that a client sends a "join" command
    // while its user_id is still present in active_users (because it did not
    // send a "leave" command). In that case, we simply remove the old
    // record first and then insert the new one.

    $this->pdo->beginTransaction();

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM active_users WHERE user_Id = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($userId));

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO active_users (user_Id, device_token, nickname, secret_code, ip_address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $stmt->execute(array($userId, $token, $name, $code, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

    $this->pdo->commit();

}

// The "leave" API command removes a user from a chat room. That user will
// no longer receive push notifications for messages sent to that room.
//
// This command takes the following POST parameters:
//
// - user_id: A unique identifier. Must be a string of 40 hexadecimal characters.
//
function handleLeave()
{
    $userId = $this->getUserId();
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM active_users WHERE user_Id = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($userId));
}

// The "update" API command gives a user a new device token.
//
// This command takes the following POST parameters:
//
// - user_id:  A unique identifier. Must be a string of 40 hexadecimal characters.
// - token: The device's device token. Must be a string of 64 hexadecimal
//          characters.
//
function handleUpdate()
{
    $userId = $this->getUserId();
    $token = $this->getDeviceToken(false);
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('UPDATE active_users SET device_token = ? WHERE user_Id = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($token, $userId));
}

// The "message" API command sends a message to all users who are registered
// with the same secret code as the sender of the message.
//
// This command takes the following POST parameters:
//
// - user_id: A unique identifier. Must be a string of 40 hexadecimal characters.
// - text: The message text. Must be a UTF-8 string of maximum 190 bytes.
//
function handleMessage()
{
    $userId = $this->getUserId();
    /*$text = $this->getString('text', self::MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH, true);*/

    // First, we get the record for the sender of the message from the
    // active_users table. That gives us the nickname, device token, and
    // secret code for that user.

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM active_users WHERE user_Id = ? LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->execute(array($userId));
    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    if ($user !== false)
    {
        // Put the sender's name and the message text into the JSON payload
        // for the push notification.
        $payload = $this->makePayload($user->nickname/*, $text*/);

        // Find the device tokens for all other users who are registered
        // for this secret code. We exclude the device token of the sender
        // of the message, so he will not get a push notification. We also
        // exclude users who have not submitted a valid device token yet.
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT device_token FROM active_users WHERE secret_code = ? AND device_token <> ? AND device_token <> '0'");
        $stmt->execute(array($user->secret_code, $user->device_token));
        $tokens = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

        // Send out a push notification to each of these devices.
        foreach ($tokens as $token)
        {
            $this->addPushNotification($token, $payload);
        }
    }
}

// Retrieves the user identifier from the POST data. If the user_id does not
// appear to be valid, the script exits with an error message.
function getUserId()
{   
    if (!isset($_POST['user_id']))
        exitWithHttpError(400, 'Missing user_id');

    $userId = trim(urldecode($_POST['user_id']));
    if (!$this->isValidUserId($userId))
        exitWithHttpError(400, 'Invalid user_id');

    return $userId;
}

// Checks whether the format of the user identifier is correct (40 hex
// characters or 32 for the simulator).
function isValidUserId($userId)
{
    if (strlen($userId) != 40 && strlen($userId) != 32)  // 32 for simulator
        return false;

    if (preg_match("/^[0-9a-fA-F]+$/", $userId) == 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}

// Retrieves the device token from the POST data. If the token does not
// appear to be valid, the script exits with an error message.
function getDeviceToken($mayBeEmpty = false)
{
    if (!isset($_POST['token']))
        exitWithHttpError(400, 'Missing device token');

    $token = trim($_POST['token']);

    // The "join" command allows a token value of "0" to be specified,
    // which is necessary in case the client did not yet obtain a device
    // token at that point. We allow such clients to join, but they will
    // not receive any notifications until they provide a valid token
    // using the "update" command.
    if ($mayBeEmpty && $token == "0")
        return $token;

    if (!$this->isValidDeviceToken($token))
        exitWithHttpError(400, 'Invalid device token');

    return $token; 

}

// Checks whether the format of the device token is correct (64 hexadecimal
// characters). Note: we have no means to verify whether the device token
// was really issued by APNS and corresponds to an actual device.
function isValidDeviceToken($deviceToken)
{
    if (strlen($deviceToken) != 64)
        return false;

    if (preg_match("/^[0-9a-fA-F]{64}$/", $deviceToken) == 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}

// Looks in the POST data for a field with the given name. If the field
// is not a valid UTF-8 string, or it is too long, the script exits with
// an error message.
function getString($name, $maxLength, $allowNewlines = false)
{
    if (!isset($_POST[$name]))
        exitWithHttpError(400, "Missing $name");

    $string = trim($_POST[$name]);
    if (!isValidUtf8String($string, $maxLength, $allowNewlines))
        exitWithHttpError(400, "Invalid $name");

    return $string;
}

// Creates the JSON payload for the push notification message. The "alert"
// text has the following format: "sender_name: message_text". Recipients
// can obtain the name of the sender by parsing the alert text up to the
// first colon followed by a space.
function makePayload($senderName, $text)
{
    // Convert the nickname of the sender to JSON and truncate to a maximum
    // length of 20 bytes (which may be less than 20 characters).
    $nameJson = $this->jsonEncode($senderName);
    $nameJson = truncateUtf8($nameJson, 20);

    // Convert and truncate the message text
    $textJson = $this->jsonEncode($text);
    $textJson = truncateUtf8($textJson, self::MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH);

    // Combine everything into a JSON string
    $payload = '{"aps":{"alert":"' . $nameJson . ': ' . $textJson . '","sound":"beep.caf"}}';
    return $payload;
}

// We don't use PHP's built-in json_encode() function because it converts
// UTF-8 characters to \uxxxx. That eats up 6 characters in the payload for
// no good reason, as JSON already supports UTF-8 just fine.
function jsonEncode($text)
{
    static $from = array("\\", "/", "\n", "\t", "\r", "\b", "\f", '"');
    static $to = array('\\\\', '\\/', '\\n', '\\t', '\\r', '\\b', '\\f', '\"');
    return str_replace($from, $to, $text);
}

// Adds a push notification to the push queue. The notification will not
// be sent immediately. The server runs a separate script, push.php, which 
// periodically checks for new entries in this database table and sends
// them to the APNS servers.
function addPushNotification($deviceToken, $payload)
{
    // Payloads have a maximum size of 256 bytes. If the payload is too
    // large (which shouldn't happen), we won't send this notification.
    if (strlen($payload) <= 256)
    {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO push_queue (device_token, payload, time_queued) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())');
        $stmt->execute(array($deviceToken, $payload));
    }

}
}


?>
```

UPDATE: removed these lines of code

```
try 
{
// Are we running in development or production mode? You can easily switch
// between these two in the Apache VirtualHost configuration.
if (!defined('APPLICATION_ENV'))
    define('APPLICATION_ENV', getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production');

// In development mode, we show all errors because we obviously want to 
// know about them. We don't do this in production mode because that might
// expose critical details of our app or our database. Critical PHP errors
// will still be logged in the PHP and Apache error logs, so it's always
// a good idea to keep an eye on them.
if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

}
else
{
    error_reporting(0);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
}

// Load the config file. I prefer to keep all configuration settings in a
// separate file so you don't have to mess around in the main code if you
// just want to change some settings.
require_once 'file://localhost/Users/user/Desktop/PushChatServer/api/api_config.php';
$config = $config[APPLICATION_ENV];

// In development mode, we fake a delay that makes testing more realistic.
// You're probably running this on a fast local server but in production
// mode people will be using it on a mobile device over a slow connection.
if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
    sleep(0);

// To keep the code clean, I put the API into its own class. Create an
// instance of that class and let it handle the request.

$api = new API($config);
$api->handleCommand();

echo "OK" . PHP_EOL;

}
catch (Exception $e)
{
// The code throws an exception when something goes horribly wrong; e.g.
// no connection to the database could be made. In development mode, we
// show these exception messages. In production mode, we simply return a
// "500 Server Error" message.

if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
    var_dump($e);
else
    exitWithHttpError(500);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function exitWithHttpError($error_code, $message = '')
{

switch ($error_code)
{
    case 400: header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request"); break;
    case 403: header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"); break;
    case 404: header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); break;
    case 500: header("HTTP/1.0 500 Server Error"); break;
}

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

if ($message != '')
    header('X-Error-Description: ' . $message);
exit;
}

function isValidUtf8String($string, $maxLength, $allowNewlines = false)
{

if (empty($string) || strlen($string) > $maxLength)
    return false;

if (mb_check_encoding($string, 'UTF-8') === false)
    return false;

// Don't allow control characters, except possibly newlines 
for ($t = 0; $t < strlen($string); $t++)
{
    $ord = ord($string{$t});

    if ($allowNewlines && ($ord == 10 || $ord == 13))
        continue;

    if ($ord < 32)
        return false;
}

return true;
}


function truncateUtf8($string, $maxLength)
{
$origString = $string;
$origLength = $maxLength;

while (strlen($string) > $origLength)
{
    $string = mb_substr($origString, 0, $maxLength, 'utf-8');
    $maxLength--;
}

return $string;
}
```

**UPDATE**: This is the Applications > MAMP > Conf > Apache > httpd.conf

I had to edit this information to get the API to work a while back. Should I change these values as well?

```
Listen 44447

<VirtualHost *:44447>
DocumentRoot "/Users/user/Desktop/PushChatServer/api"
ServerName 192.168.1.5:44447
ServerAlias pushchat.local
CustomLog "/Users/user/Desktop/PushChatServer/log/apache_access.log" combined
ErrorLog "/Users/user/Desktop/PushChatServer/log/apache_error.log"

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

<Directory "/Users/user/Desktop/PushChatServer/api">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Response to marked as duplicate: I was asked to explain how this question is different: this question is different because there is a great dialogue going on here. Feel free to shut down the other one though.

Comment: Change include to require and I bet you get a fatal error. Then change it to `require 'local/path/to/api.php';` and I bet it fixes your problem. If you look at your PHP log, you probably have a warning that `file://localhost/Users/user/Desktop/PushChatServer/api/api.php` doesn't exist.

Comment: Change the include statement to a require statement? I tried, but there is still no output.

Comment: See that's the weird thing. The path does exist. For example I just deleted all the code from under the global declaration in `api.php` and it worked. But when I added the code back it didn't echo anything.

Comment: Sure it does but you aren't accessing it within the context of the webserver that PHP is running under. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` in your Test.php and you'll get a warning.

Comment: I tried that too; I updated the `test.php` file above with the warning statement I am using. When I open it in the browser no warnings are shown. I even tried the statement you provided and the browser still shows no warnings. I'm sure the path exists, but the actual data in the `api.php` file has a structure thats preventing the global from being passed.

Comment: Put api.php in the same directory as Test.php and use `require 'Test.php';`

Comment: I did all of those things now the browser gives me this error `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare exitWithHttpError() (previously declared in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api3.php:72) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api3.php on line 89`

Comment: Somehow you are including api3 twice. Does your Test.php now have a single require and no include?

Comment: Yes. Test.php has only one require statement. I also changed the directory of `api.php` (now called api3.php ) to the same directory as `Test.php` and I also added require `Test.php;` to the top of `api3.php`

Comment: Oh that's not going to work. You should only require api3 inside Test, not the other way around.

Comment: Ok, I removed the `require 'Test.php'` from `api3.php` and refreshed and now I am getting a 500 error in the browser itself. When I click `show details` it says: `The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost:8888/Test.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.`

Comment: It's working now. The code is throwing a 500 because there was an exception: `// The code throws an exception when something goes horribly wrong; e.g.
// no connection to the database could be made. In development mode, we
// show these exception messages. In production mode, we simply return a
// "500 Server Error" message.

if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
    var_dump($e);
else
    exitWithHttpError(500);`

Comment: Then how should I go about echoing the global variable in `Test.php` if a 500 error shows up? Also, the `api3.php` file also uses a `require_once` for a file named `api_config.php`.  I decided to change that path as well since `api3.php` is now in a new directory than `api_config.php`. Now the 500 error doesn't come up but neither does any output in the browser when I open `Test.php`. This is weird

Comment: Temporarily change this line to development: `define('APPLICATION_ENV', getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'development');`

Comment: I think we're starting to narrow it down though. I deleted the following 117 lines code from the `api3.php` file and `Test.php` is now finally able to read the global variable in the browser. (Updated the question above.)

Comment: I posted my last comment before reading yours; what should I change it to?

Comment: If you read through the code you deleted, you'll see that it's in production mode and while in production mode it eats the errors. Change 'production' to 'development' where it first defines APPLICATION_ENV and you'll start seeing the real errors instead of the mystery 500 it throws.

Comment: I changed that line `if (!defined('APPLICATION_ENV'))
  define('APPLICATION_ENV', getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production');` to this line `if (!defined('APPLICATION_ENV'))
  define('APPLICATION_ENV', getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'development);` and the browser still shows blank out  put. I'm glad we we're able to narrow down the code that was interfering but so far the only way `Test.php` can read the global variable is if I delete the whole block ...

Comment: Run everything out of the same directory and get rid of this `require_once 'file://localhost/Users/user/Desktop/PushChatServer/api/api_config.php';` Use `require_once api_config.php';

Comment: Before the try add: `define("APPLICATION_ENV", "development");`

Comment: Okay, I updated the question with the `httpd.conf` file I had to edit to get the app working a while back, Should I change that stuff too?